# How to copy all .sol files in a system to a specific folder

Tags: command-line, sudo

I want to copy all the files that I have in the system with extension sol to the specific folder
can you please help me.
I tried `sudo cp / *.sol ~/SOL/`
but it doesn't work

## UPDATED:

I tried to follow the first answer, and that's what I got:

```
root@johntheripper-PORTEGE-Z835:~# find / -name *.sol | wc -l
61
root@johntheripper-PORTEGE-Z835:~# find / -type f -name '*.sol' -exec cp {} ~/SOL \;
...
...
...
root@johntheripper-PORTEGE-Z835:~# find ~/SOL -name *.sol | wc -l
26
```

As you can see 26 out of 61 file was copied, please help me to copy the rest.

Comment: Probably its due to duplicate names.(man files of same name in different directories)

Comment: this is a good point, do you know any way to kinda say in linux: 'if there is a file system.sol, create system1.sol'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bash script to copy files with specific extension in [this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-script-to-copy-specified-extension-file-from-a-directory-794890/).

There's also an [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2815552/1431600), I haven't tested it yet, but here it is:

```bash
find / -type f -name '*.sol' -exec cp '{}' ~/SOL \;
```

**EDIT:** As [phoibos](https://askubuntu.com/users/77645/phoibos) suggested, I changed the answer adding `''` in the code.

Comment: Actually, this statement copied some of the files but not all of them.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't test the script, I'll try to find another one or make one myself.

Comment: It probably didn't work for files with spaces in its name. Enclose the `{}` with `'`: `find / -type f -name '*.sol' -exec cp '{}' ~/SOL \;`

Answer (score 1):

I usually use **Midnight Commander** for this. You can install it using

```
sudo apt-get install mc
```

[image: Midnight Commander]

To find all files with a particular extension, choose Command -> Find File (Esc-?), enter your search criteria, when the search finishes click [Panelize]. All files found will be displayed in a panel from where you can review and copy them.

The explanation is a bit long but believe me it's easier than remembering the syntax of the `find` command :)

Answer (score 0):

First change to root

```
sudo -s
```

change directory to /

```
cd /
```

Now enjoy

```
cp $(locate *.sol) /path-to-directory
```

**PS:** IF the count is less it may be due to duplicate files,You can check the output

Comment: Nice and short answer! But how to rename duplicates and still copy them?